# How to intercept and replace request URL through Burp Proxy?

Tags: proxy, burp-suite

I've got a mobile app to test, and the url where requests from mobile app are sent is `mapi.example.com`, but the company told me that it would be great if I could send all requests to `mapitest.example.com`. The application response and requests are same for both urls, but the first one is in use and they would really like for me to test on the second url because of possible problems.

How can I set the intercepting proxy to change `mapi.example.com` to `mapitest.example.com`?

Comment: Are the two apps on the same IP address? It's trickier than it sounds like it should be, since doing match/replace on the header doesn't affect the target (you just send the data to the original IP address, with a changed host header), which throws a lot of people.

Comment: @Matthew yeah that is the problem for me, I did replace host through burp match and replace but target can not be changed. No they are in the same subnet though.

Comment: If you change the Hostname Resolution for `mapi.example.com` to point to the IP address for `mapitest.example.com`, AND match replace the host header, does that connect to the expected server? Don't have my Burp setup to hand to check.

Comment: @PortSwigger Useful to know - didn't want to put it as an answer since I wasn't sure, and I'm glad I didn't!

Comment: @Matthew thanks for comments and help, really grateful.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is a [sample extension](https://github.com/PortSwigger/example-traffic-redirector) to do this. Here is the description:

> This extension demonstrates how to redirect outgoing HTTP requests from one host to another. This task might arise, for example, if you have mapped out an application which then moves to a different staging URL. By simply redirecting traffic to the new hostname, you can continue to drive your testing from the original site map.
>
> The extension works as follows:
>
> - It registers itself as an HTTP listener.
> - For outgoing request messages, it retrieves the HTTP service for the request.
> - If the HTTP service host matches the "from" host, it uses a helper method to build a new HTTP service using the "to" host, and other details unchanged.
> - It updates the HTTP request with the new HTTP service.
>
> Note: The sample code uses "host1.example.org" and "host2.example.org" as the "from" and "to" hostnames. You should edit the code to use your own hostnames before using it.

Comment: What is the option for HTTPS?

Comment: @Daniel - The same. We say "HTTP" when we mean "HTTP or HTTPS" as the latter is a mouthful